# Sharing a sheet using script/macros in Google Sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sharing

I am just writing to ask if there's any way to share a Google Sheet worksheet with specific people using Google Apps Script Editor?

My ultimate goal is have it so the macro button share's the sheet with a set amount of addresses then emails them the shareable link, so they can see the sheet after receiving the email.

If there is a way, could you kindly explain/show me how? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, there's a Google Sheet add-on called [Neo-Share](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neo-share/kjkdakhicldpimlimkijcmmnpemikafg?utm_source=permalink), that allows you to share the sheet to specific people with the option of choosing between Editors and Viewers.

If you want to do it yourself [this section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) of the docs is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yup! This is what I was looking for, thank you very much.